# How to loop an json array with AutoIt

Tags: arrays, json, automation, autoit

I have an array in this form

```
[{"var1":"test1","var2":"test1"},{"var1":"test2","var2":"test2"},{"var1":"test3","var2":"test3"}]
```

I want to make an automation script that loop the array and return `var2` of each object

The result should be like that

```
test1
test2
test3
```

I have this working script but I dont know how to apply it to my case since each element is an object in json form

```
#include <array.au3>

Local $array[5] = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

_ArrayDisplay($array)

For $i = 0 To UBound($array) - 1

    ConsoleWrite("Testing " & $array[$i] & @CRLF)

Next

_ArrayDisplay($array)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Json UDF](https://github.com/J2TeaM/AutoIt-Imgur-UDF/tree/master/include) for parsing JSON in Autoit.
Don't forget to add `Json.au3` and `BinaryCall.au3` to folder of your script.

Example for your question:

```
#include "Json.au3"
#include <Array.au3>

$sJson = '[{"var1":"test1","var2":"test1"},{"var1":"test2","var2":"test2"},{"var1":"test3","var2":"test3"}]'
$oJSON = Json_Decode($sJson)

If IsArray($oJSON) Then
    For $i=0 to UBound($oJSON)-1
        $res = Json_ObjGet($oJSON[$i], "var2")
            ConsoleWrite($res & @CRLF)
    Next
EndIf
```

Answer (score 2):

You have options with no UDFs as well:

```
$str = '[{"var1":"test1","var2":"test1"},{"var1":"test2","var2":"test2"},{"var1":"test3","var2":"test3"}]'
$aVar2 = StringRegExp($str , '"var2":"(.*?)"' , 3)
$sOut = ""

For $i = 0 To UBound($aVar2) - 1
    $sOut &= $aVar2[$i] & @LF
Next

MsgBox(0, '' , $sOut)
```